# Can't save models to DynamoDB using Swift 4

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, swift4, xcode9

I started a new project using XCode9 and Swift4. I copied the basic example code for saving models to DynamoDB but I keep getting the following error:

`Amazon DynamoDB Save Error: Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain Code=0 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=com.amazon.coral.validate#ValidationException, message=Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes}`

My project only contains the example code provided and nothing else, how can I get my models to save?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The work-around until Swift 4 is supported properly is to put

```
@objcMembers
```

before the class declaration for your model class, as described in this bug report.

https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-ios/issues/750

This fixed the issue for me without having to downgrade to Swift 3.

Comment: Omg. Thank you for ending my misery after being stuck on this for 3 hours.

Comment: This is obviously the better answer :)

Comment: omg,I spend 3 days to resolve this issue, recode and recreate aws services but still not working. This may help me a lot ..thanks :D

Comment: I put a few code examples & learnings here - might be useful.  https://gist.github.com/sarah-j-smith/f10f313930dfd0e8662d3af0d3f605ce  - feel free to ping me if I can help.  :-)

Answer (score 0):

DynamoDB doesn't seem to support Swift4 yet. I downloaded the sample project provided by AWS (MySampleApp) and set the target's build settings `Swift Language Version` to `Swift 4.0`, made slight modifications so it would compile, and I got the same error.

Reducing the `Swift Language Version` to `Swift 3.2` in both the sample app and my own project fixed the problem.